# Problema con permisos para enviar un sms

Tags: sms, twilio

Tengo un problema, y es que contraté un número mexicano en Twilio, y a la hora de enviar un sms a otro teléfono mexicano, me da error y me pone:

> The app returned "Permission to send an SMS has not been enabled for the region indicated by the 'To' number:

Answer (score 0):

Hay una sección en la configuración que se llama Geo permissions. Intenta configurando ahi los países en los cuales se recibirán los mensaje